# Multi align equation right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am trying to obtain the following alignment for my three equation

[image]

The best I have been able to do is the following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{align*}
  r(\theta)    & = & (x_0 + a \cos x) i & + & (y_0 + a \sin x) j & \\
  r'(\theta)   & = &      - a \sin x  i & + &       (a \cos x) j & \\
  F(r(\theta)) & = &                0 i & + & (x_0 + a \sin x) j &
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

However this leaves huge whitespaces in the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}% really? that is very 20th century, why not utf8?

\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{3}
  r(\theta)    ={}&&  (x_0 + a \cos x) i  + {}&& (y_0 + a \sin x) j \\
  r'(\theta)   ={}&&      - a \sin x  i   + {}&&       (a \cos x) j \\
  F(r(\theta)) ={}&&                0 i   + {}&& (x_0 + a \sin x) j
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

`alignat` is a variant of `align` that avoids adding extra space. You need `&&` so you only use the right aligned columns not the left aligned, and then you need `{}` after the `=` and `+` to preserve the correct spacing as they are before the `&` not after.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `array` for this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ii}{\mathbf{\,i}}
\newcommand{\jj}{\mathbf{\,j}}

\[
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} r @{} r}
  \mathbf{r}(\theta)             & (x_0 + a \cos x) \ii +{} & (y_0 + a \sin x) \jj  \\
  \mathbf{r}'(\theta)            &      - a \sin x  \ii +{} &       (a \cos x) \jj  \\
  \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(\theta)) &                0 \ii +{} & (x_0 + a \sin x) \jj 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]